# OpenSAML3.3 Correct way to read (adfs) FederationService.xml?

Tags: java, xml, metadata, adfs, opensaml

I'm integrating OpenSAML 3.3 in my application, and instead of hard-coding all the urls etc, I would like to be able to use the configuration XMLs.

I was given such an XML file for a adfs instance, it is 'FederationMetadata.xml'

This is the snippet I used to read it:

```
    InitializationService.initialize();
    FilesystemMetadataResolver idpMetaDataProvider = new FilesystemMetadataResolver( new File("/home/raudenaerde/sso/FederationMetadata.xml") );
    idpMetaDataProvider.setRequireValidMetadata(true);
    idpMetaDataProvider.setParserPool(new BasicParserPool());
    idpMetaDataProvider.initialize();
```

However, this gave me this error:

> ```
> > Exception in thread "main"
> > net.shibboleth.utilities.java.support.component.ComponentInitializationException:
> > Component identifier can not be null
> ```

Using an github project (https://github.com/coveo/saml-client) that uses OpenSAML 2.6.4 I had no problems reading it, but I'd like to stick with the newest version 3.3.

Am I missing some basic set-up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 things that needed to be fixed:

1. In OpenSaml v3 many class instances are required to have an ID, `setId(String)` must be called before `initialize()`
2. The `BasicParserPool` needs to be initialized as well.

Complete working code:

```
    InitializationService.initialize();

    FilesystemMetadataResolver idpMetaDataProvider = new FilesystemMetadataResolver( new File( "/home/raudenaerde/sso/FederationMetadata.xml" ) );
    idpMetaDataProvider.setRequireValidMetadata( true );
    idpMetaDataProvider.setId( "myId" );
    BasicParserPool pool = new BasicParserPool();

    pool.initialize();
    idpMetaDataProvider.setParserPool( pool );
    idpMetaDataProvider.initialize();

    for ( EntityDescriptor idpEntityDescriptor : idpMetaDataProvider )
    {

        System.out.println( idpEntityDescriptor.getID() );
        for ( SingleSignOnService sss : idpEntityDescriptor.getIDPSSODescriptor( SAMLConstants.SAML20P_NS ).getSingleSignOnServices() )
        {
            if ( sss.getBinding().equals( SAMLConstants.SAML2_REDIRECT_BINDING_URI ) )
            {
                System.out.println( sss.getLocation() );
            }

        }
        for ( ArtifactResolutionService ars : idpEntityDescriptor.getIDPSSODescriptor( SAMLConstants.SAML20P_NS ).getArtifactResolutionServices() )
        {
            if ( ars.getBinding().equals( SAMLConstants.SAML2_SOAP11_BINDING_URI ) )
            {
                System.out.println( ars.getLocation() );
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Without your help, it would have been very difficult for me to guess that the FilesystemMetadataResolver type is an iterable one via the IterableMetadataSource interface. Thank you a lot!